# Track Hadoop HDFS state

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How can I track the changes happening on HDFS. 
I would like to know within a particular time frame(example 8:00am to 9:00am) changes taking place on HDFS. We need to track changes on the file not on the content of the file.

Can some help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the notify API. See :

```
stream = this.dfs.getInotifyEventStream();
Event raw_event = null;
while ((raw_event = this.stream.poll()) != null) {
    logEventFromHadoop(raw_event);
}
```